# How do I find the element by class name for a button on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to try make a script that auto-clicks a button, but I can't find what to put in the class name. How do I find it?

```
window.onload=function(){
    setInterval(autoClick,100);
  }
  function autoClick(){
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("???").length>0){
    document.getElementsByClassName("???")[0].click();
  }
}
```

I don't know how to get the element by class name.

Comment: Does your button has a class assigned? Post you HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to click with coordinates use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();`

https://codepen.io/niko8888/pen/aryoMb?editors=0010

If you are using Chrome, open up the inspector, inspect the element you want to click.  Right click over the element in the Elements panel and then scroll down to `Copy > Copy JS Path` and then paste the result.  It should be a querySelector for that specific element.

Comment: There is no element name. How do click with coordinates instead?

Comment: @DavidtheGoat123 if you want to click with coordinates look above, I edited my answer.  Click on the codepen,